# Compiling all C files and creating executable with Makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have a C project, which has the following file structure:

```
Makefile
src
 |-utils
 |   |--vic.c
 |   |--vic.h
 |-mod
 |  |--type.c
 |  |--type.h
 |-bb.c
 |-bb.h
 |-main.c
```

So, at the root directory I have the actual `Makefile` and the `src` directory, which includes the source files. Inside the `src` directory there are multiple `.c` and `.h` files along with the `main.c` file, and there are other directories which also contain other `.c` and `.h` files. Please note that the above shown file structure is kept short for brevity. I want to create a `Makefile` that will automatically compile everything and generate an executable `main` program, and also delete the object files generated during the compilation. Currently, I have something like this:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=
RM=rm -rf
OUT=main
SRC=src
OBJ=obj

SOURCES=$(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst $(SRC)/%.c, $(OBJ)/%.o, $(SOURCES))

all: build

build: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
    $(RM) $(OBJ)

$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(SRC) -c $< -o $@

debug: CFLAGS+=-DDEBUG
debug: build

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJ) $(OUT)
```

But that doesn't seem to work as expected, as when I issue `make` command, it returns the following error message:

> Assembler messages: Fatal error: can't create obj/main.o: No such file
>   or directory

Any ideas how to achieve what I want?

Comment: You are making trouble for yourself by distributing your sources in a directory tree, instead of all in the same directory, and at the same time trying to write a single `Makefile` that *dynamically* discovers and builds all the sources.  This is not beyond GNU `make`'s capabilities, but the effort you will spend getting it to work would probably be better spent on solving the problem a different way.

Comment: Alternatives include hand-writing all the sources into the Makefile (possibly with the help of piping in the output of an `ls` command), or at least making a static list of all the subdirectories, or setting up a separate Makefile in each subdirectory and performing a good old recursive `make`.

Comment: There are also better alternatives for keeping the source directory clean, such as setting up for and performing VPATH builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you `rm -rf obj/` after each step, but there's no `mkdir -p obj/` to replace it.

Since GNU `make` will, itself, remove intermediate targets, I don't see why you would do `$(RM) $(OBJ)`, but your `%.o` target could have a line like
`mkdir -p "$(shell dirname "$@")"`
… to ensure that the destination directory exists.

PS: your output is named `build` rather than `main` because that's the name you gave it …